# Why doesn’t the reaction between 3-mercaptopropionic acid and methyl iodide yield a methyl ester?

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, halides, organosulfur-compounds

#### Problem

> [image: Reaction between acrylic acid and H2S; reaction between former product W and CH3I]

#### Answer

> [image: W: 3-sulfanylpropanoic acid; X: 3-(methylsulfanyl)propanoic acid]

#### Question

I don’t understand why 3‐methylthiopropionic acid (**X**) is the correct answer. Wouldn’t sulfur and carbon have similar electronegativities?

As the consequence, isn’t it more likely that the second step involves hydroxyl’s oxygen forming a dative covalent bond with the partially positive carbon of methyl iodide?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't really have an alcohol. With the carbonyl group also there you have a carboxylic acid instead. The combination of a carbonyl group directly bonded to hydroxyl is in fact considered a separate functional group called "carboxyl".

With this coupling to the electron-withdrawing carbonyl group, the hydroxyl portion of a carboxyl group is not nearly as nucleophilic as it would be in a simple alcohol and also not as nucleophilic as the hydrosulfide function at the other end of the W molecule. The methyl iodide then attacks at the more nucleophilic site to give the X product.